# Dynamic dosing recipe for accurate pH

Tags: neural-network, predictive-modeling, prediction, dynamic-batching

I want to have a script for adjusting dosage of ingredients in each batch dynamically. Assuming that the requirement is to have a specific value of pH from each batch but with the variation of raw material concentration making the output pH varied even the exact amount were dosed into a mixer. Hence I want to have a prediction model which give output as a suggested dosage of each material for the next batch by learning from the actual dose in and pH value from the previous batch. Which model should I deploy?